# polymer 1.0 : Disable paper-tab

Tags: polymer

How can a disable the selection of a paper tab within the paper-tabs element?

There is a link in the paper-tabs docs but it doesn't work!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `disabled` attribute, the button will be disabled. For instance:

```
<paper-fab disabled icon="add"></paper-fab>
```

Comment: you mean to add a paper-fab inside a paper-fab and then disable the paper-fab?

Comment: sorry I meant a paper-fab inside a paper-tab .. my bad

Comment: do you have a code snippet of what you have so far?

Comment: Hi.. yeah, but I kind made a work around by using data-attributes

Comment: data-attributes and mutation observers

Comment: @BenThomas How to return to enable after set disabled ?

Comment: You simply need to get a reference to the element and set the disabled attribute to false. For instance `this.$$("#my-fab-button").disabled = false;`

Comment: Also for enabling/disabling paper-tab might be bound some boolean property to disabled attribute of paper-tab.
<paper-tabs selected="{{selectedTab}}">
                <paper-tab disabled="[[someProperty]]">Some label</paper-tab>
                <paper-tab disabled="[[someProperty]]">Some other label</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>